# How to filter out null groups in a Row Group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I was wondering if someone would be able to help me remove any null Groups in a Row Group I have

```
STATUS    |  1  |  2  |  3  |
-----------------------------
          | 554 | 564 | 132 |
-----------------------------
Status 1  | 489 | 784 | 315 |
```

I would like to have my row group filter out that blank status. Would anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set the Row Visibility based on an expression like `=IIF(IsNothing(Field!Status.Value),True,False)`

Of course if you are not showing the data anywhere else I would suggest filtering it out in your query.

`select 
status, otherField, yetAnotherField
from someTable
where status <> null`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the expression you have listed above does not work for me and unfortunately i am using this dataset elsewhere. the error i get using the expression is `The processing of FilterExpression for the grouping cannot be performed. Cannot compare data of types System.Boolean and System.String. Please check the data type returned by the FilterExpression` Any ideas?

Comment: Are you setting the expression on the ''Filter' or Row Visibility? This expression should be set on the Row Visibility within the Tablix row you are working. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220590.aspx

Comment: I applied it to the Visibility setting in the group properties and this worked. Thank you for you help. I also edited your posed because it should be `Fields` and not `Field`